# Rundeck API - get job schedule

Tags: rundeck

For Rundeck community edition 3.3.10 is there a way of getting a scheduled job's schedule frequency via the API? e.g. if the schedule is `0 20/15 * ? * * *` then an API call that will either return this string, or the frequency part of every 15 minutes. I have looked at the `job/<ID>/info` and `job/<ID>/executions` endpoints, but I am unable to get the actual schedule frequency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Job Forecast API Endpoint](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/api/rundeck-api.html#get-job-forecast). That info is available in the "futureScheduledExecutions" response section.

Comment: That might work - taking the difference of two successive future executions should be consistent with the schedule frequency.